# Model can not be updated by multiple create model query jobs at the same time - BQML Error

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BQML to build a model, but I keep receiving an error that states I can't run more than one model concurrently. While in fact there are no other models running anywhere and I am only working on creating one. My whole code and the screenshot of the error are included below. I was unable to locate any relevant material.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.MKT_DS.HS_KITCHEN_PROEJECT_SELLING_MODEL`
OPTIONS (model_type='BOOSTED_TREE_CLASSIFIER',
input_label_cols=['Y'],
MAX_TREE_DEPTH = 6,
LEARN_RATE = 0.01,
COLSAMPLE_BYTREE = 0.8,
SUBSAMPLE = 0.8,
BOOSTER_TYPE = 'gbtree',
DATA_SPLIT_METHOD = 'RANDOM',
DATA_SPLIT_EVAL_FRACTION = 0.2,
MAX_ITERATIONS = 20,
MAX_PARALLEL_TRIALS = 5,
ENABLE_GLOBAL_EXPLAIN = TRUE,
AUTO_CLASS_WEIGHTS = TRUE
) AS 
SELECT * EXCEPT(HH_ID,id) FROM `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.MKT_DS.KITCHEN_PROJECT_SELLING_TRAIN`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally occurs when a user cancels a query. In the ML server we have to wait for the current training query to finish and then cancel the following operations. But sometimes the training query can take a long time to finish. During this time if another query creates the same model, it triggers the error:

> Model can not be updated by multiple create model query jobs at the
> same time.

More information can be found here: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#limitations).

**Edit**:

To check the running jobs you can use [Information Schema.jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs). This  will show real-time metadata about all BigQuery jobs in the current project.

Query:

```
SELECT
 query,
 job_id,
 creation_time
FROM [PROJECT_ID.]`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE state != "DONE"
```

Comment: I see, but how would I know if there is a "CREATE MODEL" query already running from a previous cancellation.