# No job running but "Model can not be updated by multiple create model query jobs at the same time" in BQML

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery ML but get the error **"Model can not be updated by multiple create model query jobs at the same time"** when trying to train a new version of the model (Same as in this question [Model can not be updated by multiple create model query jobs at the same time - BQML Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75729068/4113067) ).

But I have no other job running, i.e. this query returns nothing:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `MY_PROJECT_NAME.region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
  state != "DONE"
```

I suspect it is caused by some training `job_stages` still running.
Any insights on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that we are working on a solution on our side. Currently the workaround is to (1) delete the existing model (using DROP MODEL statement query or other methods) and (2) create a new model using CREATE MODEL.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was able to fix the issue with the workaround you've proposed. My workflow is now to do a DROP MODEL IF EXISTS before any CREATE MODEL. 
Do you have an estimated ETA for the fix on BQ's side?

Comment: You don't have to DROP the model every time, as the error only happens in some edge cases when our backend is being updated. At the same time we are rolling out the fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and search for failed jobs with this query:

```
SELECT
   job_id,
  creation_time,
  user_email,
   error_result
 FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
 WHERE error_result.reason != "Null"
ORDER BY creation_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Alternatively you can try this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
  state != "DONE"
```

But I believe the recommended approach is to file a support case as they can view your logs and they can cancel a job from the backend.